# AngularJS UI Components

Tags: angularjs, uicomponents

I need to know whether AngularJS only enable architecture for develop the applications and it self doesn't provide any UI components and Widgets (calenders, charts etc)?
Whether we have to get them (UI components) only via the third party UI Frame works?

Comment: they don't and they shouldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it self doesn't provide any UI components and Widgets

try angularUI
https://github.com/angular-ui

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS itself doesn't provide any UI controls, here are some other resources for UI controls:

[Bootstrap with AngularJS](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

**[Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete)** - This project provides a set of reusable, well-tested, and accessible UI components based on Material Design.

[Kendo UI controls - calender](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/calendar/angular)

[3 AngularJS UI Frameworks](http://angularjs4u.com/ui/top-angularjs-ui-frameworks/)